# How to choose 10 different integers from range (0, 99)

Tags: python

I want to choose 10 random integers from 0 to 99. I know I can use:

```
random.randint(a, b)
```

But how to tell the randint() that I only want different integers.

Do I have to just check after each random generation to see if the integer has already been generated and call the method again? That does not seem like an optimal solution.

Comment: @Felix: It is random, it just is not *uniformly* random any more ;)

Comment: @Felix King: It's a valid thing to do. It's called sampling without replacement.

Comment: @Armen, It should still be uniform. Not on the range(0, 99) but on the set of 10 element combinations of that set.

Comment: @aaronasterling: No, the distribution function of the ten-tuple <x1, x2...,x10> will not be uniform on the set [0,99]x[0,99]...[0,99]. Will it?

Comment: @Armen, that's a different set but possibly more appropriate. I suppose that it depends on the implementation but _I_ for one, wouldn't be satisfied with a choice function that wasn't uniform on either the set you proposed (if I cared about order) or the set that I proposed (if I didn't care about order). It's certainly possible to construct a uniform choice on either of the sets. I believe tvanfosson's answer is uniform on the product and I would have a hard time believing that Pythons `sample` function wasn't uniform on it as well.

Comment: @aaronasterling: I agree completely. It's just Felix King had left a now-deleted pedantic comment that the OP's solution wouldn't yield random numbers any more, so I started a pedantic battle :) That's all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from random import sample

sample(range(0, 100), 10)
```

Comment: If you want to use a large range, you can use `xrange`, as mentioned in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample), to avoid allocating a huge list of numbers that you don't care about.

Comment: Just always use `xrange` here.  It's hard to think of any reason to ever use `range` in this case.

Comment: @Fayden: `range` in Python 3 *is* Python 2's `xrange`.

Comment: I know, which is why I said this. I use Python 3, therefore there is no reason for me to use xrange! But I entirely get your point, we should use xrange in Python 2.

Comment: That is why I typically add the following in the start of my modules who have to be used under both Python 2 and 3: `try: xrange; except NameError: xrange= range` (change `;` to `\n` of course)

Answer (score 8):

Here's general strategy that is language independent. Generate an array of 100 entries from 0 to 99.  Choose a random number from 0 to 99 and swap the entry at that position with the element at position 0.  Then successively choose a random number from i to 99, where i = 1 to 9 and swap the element at that position with the one at element i.  Your 10 random numbers are in the first 10 positions of the array.

Comment: @LukeH - thanks for the reference.  This is, indeed, a variant of the Fisher-Yates in-place shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a solution depending on what you will need to use this for... but have you thought of splitting it off into 10 different random number generators? Ex. 0-9, 10-19, 20-29, etc. I guess that's not really as "random" as you are specifying different ranges and are guaranteed 1 number from each range. The only other solution I can think of would be to have a list of the random integers, iterate through and check to see if the random number has been generated yet and if so run the random.randint() again.

Comment: I like tvanfosson's solution below better than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a language independent solution:

```
integer numbers[10];
for(integer i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    integer num = randomInteger(min = 0, max = (99 - i));
    boolean hasFoundDuplicate = false;
    for(integer j = 0; j < i && hasFoundDuplicate == false; j += 1) {
        if(numbers[j] == num) {
            num = 99 + 1 - i + j;
            hasFoundDuplicate = true;
        }
    }
    numbers[i] = num;
}
```